Why does my simple HTTP server need two instances running in order to work?
Noob here. I have been following Beej's Guide to Network Programming and tried constructing an HTTP server following the style of code used in the book. I am running FreeBSD 14.0.
My issue is that all my server programs require two instances running at once in order to successfully render the connection -- IOW, starting the program twice via ./httpserver & ./httpserver or an equivalent method. The connection will be refused if only one instance is running.
The code below is for my stupid-simple concurrent HTTP server. I also tried one using the select() function for a different approach, but it had the same exact quirk (needing two running instances to work).
// include statements omitted 

int main(void) {
    int sockfd;
    int rv;
    int yes = 1;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, "8000", &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "httpserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (sockfd < 0) {
            continue;
        }

        setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "httpserver: could not bind to any address\n");
        freeaddrinfo(res);
        exit(1);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    if (listen(sockfd, 10) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    // main loop. 
    while (1) {
        int newfd;
        struct sockaddr_storage theiraddr;
        socklen_t addrlen;

        addrlen = sizeof(theiraddr);
        newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&theiraddr, &addrlen);

        if (newfd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        if (!fork()) { // Child process
            close(sockfd); // Child doesn't need the listener
            char buf[4096];
            int nbytes = recv(newfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            if (nbytes > 0) {
                buf[nbytes] = '\0';
                printf("Received request: %s\n", buf);

                // Simple HTTP response
                const char *response =
                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                    "Content-Length: 70\r\n"
                    "\r\n"
                    "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>";
                if (send(newfd, response, strlen(response), 0) == -1) {
                    perror("send");
                }
            } else if (nbytes == 0) {
                printf("server: socket %d hung up\n", newfd);
            } else {
                perror("recv");
            }
            close(newfd);
            exit(0); // Exit child process after handling connection
        }

        // Parent process
        close(newfd); // Parent doesn't need this socket
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}


Could anyone share why they think this is happening?

Works fine for me running it once.  Try running netstat -ntl before and after running one instance of the program and see if you can see the listening port.

if (!fork()) { // Child process?  And if fork() fails and returns ( pid_t ) -1?

You can't have two server processes binding to the same address+port, so it doesn't make much sense to run the server twice.

My guess is that getaddrinfo() returns two addresses: IPv6 and IPv4. First instance binds to IPv6 and can't accept IPv4 connection (or vice versa). Second instance fails to bind to first address because of address in use, and binds to second one.

See also this answer. People can't reproduce your issue in Linux because of dual stack enabled (in FreeBSD it is likely disabled). I can reproduce the issue in Linux with IPV6_V6ONLY socket option, which confirms my suspicion from previous comment. Print relevant error messages in case of bind() and other functions failures. Also you can print some debug info, e.g. address families returned by getaddrinfo().
